# How can I make the antecedent more targeted?

Tags: grammar, ambiguity

> We find that two properties of the function that describes A **that** the recent literature calls B and C play a vital role.

For the bolded that, my intended antecedent is "properties", but I am worried that the reader may think "A" is the antecedent. Is there a way to avoid this confusion?

Comment: Does this have to be one sentence? It would read much better as two. Also, FWIW, the antecedent is "two properties of the function that describes A".

Comment: @gotube How to break it into two sentences?

Comment: Analyzing the sentence carefully, I'm not certain I know what it means: There's a function that describes A. This function has two properties that play a vital role (in what??) (do functions have properties?). The recent literature calls these two properties B and C. Do I understand the meaning correctly?

Comment: @gotube There's a function that describes A. This function has two properties that play a vital role (in what?? [_It is mentioned before this sentence, so I omit it here._]) (do functions have properties? [_property C is stronger than property B, so some functions satisfy property C, some satisfy property B but not C, some do not satisfy property B_]). The recent literature calls these two properties B and C.

Comment: I can't follow all this vague talk about A, B, C, properties, functions, satisfaction and so on. Hiding what you're trying to say makes it impossible for me to give you a good answer. It would be much, much simpler for you to just tell us what you're talking about.

Comment: @gotube "_We find that two properties of the function that describes the receiver's cost of information acquisition that the recent literature calls Sequential Learning Proofness (SLP) and the more restrictive Indifference to Sequential Learning (ISL) play a vital role._"

Comment: Is this in the context of document that's as highly technical as this sentence?

Comment: @gotube I am writing a technical essay and this is the original sentence.

Comment: "Within the function that describes the receiver's cost of information acquisition, two properties play a vital role. The recent literature refers to them as, Sequential Learning Proofness (SLP) and the more restrictive Indifference to Sequential Learning (ISL)."

Comment: @gotube Thank you very much! It occurs to me that maybe I can eliminate the first attributive clause. How about this: "We find that two properties of the receiver's information acquisition cost function play a vital role. The recent literature refers to them as, Sequential Learning Proofness (SLP) and the more restrictive Indifference to Sequential Learning (ISL)."

Comment: Sure. They're both good, and it's a matter of style which to use. I prefer mine because it clearly separates the context from the main idea, and keeps the subject and verb close together. In yours, "properties" and "play" are quite far apart, which reduces readability. That said, in a technical paper, this kind of writing is some more acceptable than other contexts, but the trend these days is to prioritize readability.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the antecedent:

> We find that two properties of the function that describes A — properties that the recent literature calls B and C — play a vital role.

Split the sentence:

> We find that two properties of the function that describes A play a vital role. These properties are called B and C in the recent literature.

Reorder the sentence:

> The function that describes A has two properties, called A and B in the recent literature, that we find play a vital role.